# Convert data file into an array of your Employee class

Tags: c#

Hi I'm new to programming and I can *read the file* but I don't know how to put it in an *array* so I can sort it by name, number, rate, and hour and put it in my employee class constructor. Here is what i got so far

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StreamReader employee = new StreamReader("employees.txt");
        string data = employee.ReadLine();
        while (data !=null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(data);
            data = employee.ReadLine();
        }
```

and my employee class I know that there are parameters that make the set and get easier but i am not allowed to do that yet:

```
class Employee
{
    private String name;
    private int number;
    private decimal rate;
    private double hours;
    private decimal gross;

    public Employee(String name, int number, decimal rate, double hours)
    {
        name = name;
        number = number;
        rate = rate;
        hours = hours;
    }

    public decimal GetGross()
    {
        return gross = rate*hours;
    }

    public double GetHours()
    {
        return hours;
    }

    public String GetName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public int GetNumber()
    {
        return number;
    }

    public decimal GetRate()
    {
        return rate;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "name: " + name + 
               " number: " + number + 
               " rate: " + rate + 
               " hours: " + hours;
    }

    public void SetHours(double Hours)
    {
        hours = Hours;
    }

    public void SetName(String Name)
    {
        name = Name;
    }

    public void SetNumber(int Number)
    {
        number = Number;
    }

    public void SetRate(decimal Rate)
    {
        rate = Rate;
    }
}
```

I have been stuck on this for a few hours just started programming hope you will help me

```
Bruce Wayne,    123456, 25.88, 35.50
Clark Kent,     232344, 25.88, 38.75
Diana Prince,   657659, 27.62, 30.25
Hal Jordan,     989431, 23.14, 44.25
```

Comment: You're missing a part of the puzzle: your input data.

Comment: can u add the sample data of text file

Comment: sorry, just added the data

Comment: this is data i got comma seperated, no space added

Comment: Why don't you use C# properties? decimal Rate {get;set;}

Comment: I wonder if the following line in constructor actually works? name = name; Shouldn't we specify this? this.name=name

Comment: @XtuhCy You have mistake in your code change your ctor body to the following:        this.name = name;
this.number = number;
this.rate = rate;
this.hours = hours;

Comment: How to use properties in C# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties

Comment: Hi, I know I'm late the the party.. But your data Look like a CSV. Do you accept the help of [CSV Helper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the data in a file (`employees.txt`), you can easily parse it as simple (no quotations) csv:

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

... 

Employee[] data = File
  .ReadLines(@"employees.txt")
  .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) // skip empty lines if we have them
  .Select(line => line.Split(','))
  .Select(items => new Employee(
     items[0], 
     int.Parse(items[1]), 
     decimal.Parse(items[2], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
     double.Parse(items[3], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
  .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

`ReadLines` to read all lines of file. Then, for each file, you extract the info and inject them to the constructor of `Employee`

```
var lines = File.ReadLines("employees.txt").Where(s=> !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s));
var list = new List<Employee>();
foreach(var line in lines)
{
    var arr = line.Split(',');
    var name = arr[0].Trim();
    var number = int.Parse(arr[1]);
    var rate = decimal.Parse(arr[2]);
    var hour  = double.Parse(arr[3]);
    var emp = new Employee(name, number, rate, hour);
    list.Add(emp);
}
```

Comment: I suggest changing `File.ReadAllLines` into `File.AllLines`: we don't want a (premature materialized) array in the context

Comment: `.Trim()` is redundant in the context and can be dropped (`Parse` is smart enough)

Answer (score 0):

```
        string line;
        List<Employee> lstEmpDetails = new List<Employee>();

        // Read the file and display it line by line.
        using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"d:\read.txt"))
        {
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] words = line.Split(',');
                lstEmpDetails.Add(new Employee(words[0], int.Parse(words[1]), decimal.Parse(words[2]), double.Parse(words[3])));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please, do not put direct close of `IDisposable`: `file.Close();` but wrap into `using`: `using(System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"d:\read.txt")) {...}`

Comment: `words[0].ToString()` is redundant: `words[0]`; there's no need to convert `string` to `string`